# GPIO in Rapberry Pi no Turn Off

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

Write this code with python3. But don't work. Only the relay comes on but it does not turn off.

I need this turn on and after 3 seconds to turn off.

This is my code:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

channel = 23

# GPIO setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.OUT)


def motor_on(pin): 
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)  # Turn motor on


def motor_off(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)  # Turn motor off


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        motor_on(channel)
        time.sleep(2)
        motor_off(channel)
        time.sleep(2)

        GPIO.cleanup()

        motor_on(channel)
        time.sleep(2)
        motor_off(channel)
        time.sleep(2)

    GPIO.cleanup()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your code in general -- the indentation at the end should be like this

```
    try:
        motor_on(channel)
        time.sleep(2)
        motor_off(channel)
        time.sleep(2)

        GPIO.cleanup()

        motor_on(channel)
        time.sleep(2)
        motor_off(channel)
        time.sleep(2)

        GPIO.cleanup()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

and as above, running `motor_on()` and `motor_off()` after `GPIO.cleanup()` will give you errors if you don't run `GPIO.setmode()` and `GPIO.setup()` again first -- but with those things fixed, your code works perfectly fine to turn an LED on and off, so there may be a problem with your circuit.